# Register generic interface with fallback

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I would like to register the service `IInterface<T>` such that if there exists in some assembly a class implementing `IInterface<T>`, it uses that, but if that class doesn't exist, it uses `Fallback<T>`.

So, for example, let's say I have defined a class `CatImplementer : IInterface<Cat>`.

If I asked the container for `IInterface<Cat>` I would get `CatImplementer`. But if I asked for `IInterface<Dog>`, I would get `Fallback<Dog>`, because I haven't created a class implementing `IInterface<Dog>`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example, you don't need to do anything special whether you're registering the types explicitly:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IInterface<Cat>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(CatImplementer)));
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IInterface<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Fallback<>)));
```

Or implicitly:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().Pick().WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

In both cases, the following code:

```
IInterface<Cat> cat = container.Resolve<IInterface<Cat>>();
IInterface<Dog> dog = container.Resolve<IInterface<Dog>>();

Console.WriteLine("cat.GetType() -> " + cat.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("dog.GetType() -> " + dog.GetType());
```

When using these objects:

```
public interface IInterface<T> { }

public class CatImplementer : IInterface<Cat> { }

public class Fallback<T> : IInterface<T> { }

public class Cat { }

public class Dog { }
```

Will print:

```
cat.GetType() -> ConsoleApplication1.CatImplementer
dog.GetType() -> ConsoleApplication1.Fallback`1[ConsoleApplication4.Dog]
```

If that doesn't work for you (using Castle 3.3) in your actual use case, then there must be a critical piece that's different.  Feel free to add to your question if that's the case.